# Why would a large TCP transfer randomly stall until data is sent in the opposite direction?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, network-programming, boost-asio

I have two programs I'm writing that communicate with a simple ad-hoc protocol over TCP. They work together to transfer large (1-64 MB) binary files from the server to the client.

There's an issue with data transmission stalling that causes a socket timeout on the receive side. I'd like to better understand what is happening in this situation, so that I can learn from this and improve my code.

### The Setup

##### TCP Server

The TCP server (written with `boost::asio` using the async functions) that accepts a connection from a client and sends "HI". It runs on a separate, nearby ARM64 host, connected via a simple switch over Ethernet.

When the server receives "GET" it responds by writing a large amount of data (header "DATA" + 1MB binary data + footer "END" = 1048606 bytes) to the socket using `async_write()`. I believe my data lifetimes are correct.

I've also tried synchronous writes, and it seems to have no effect on this issue.

##### TCP Client

The TCP client is written in Python, and runs on a PC. It uses the low-level socket interface to connect to the server with a blocking socket:

```
    sock = socket.create_connection((address, port), timeout=30.0)
```

After connecting, it consumes the "HI" and responds with "GET".

After sending the "GET", it enters a loop that collects all bytes of data sent by the server.

The TCP client knows, a priori, how much data to expect from the server, so it can loop on `recv()` until all that data is received:

```py
import socket

def recv_len(sock: socket.socket, length: int) -> bytes:
    chunks = []
    bytes_rx = 0
    while bytes_rx < length:
        chunk = sock.recv(min(length - bytes_rx, 4096))
        if chunk == b'':
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        chunks.append(chunk)
        bytes_rx += len(chunk)
    return b''.join(chunks)


def main():

    sock = socket.create_connection((address, port), timeout=30.0)

    get = recv_len(sock, 3)  # receive "HI\n"
    sock.sendall(b"GET\n")

    data = recv_len(sock, 1048606)
```

The client then processes the data and repeats, by sending another "GET" message.

### The Problem

When run once, the client and server seem to work correctly.

Now, I have the client running in a tight loop, sending many "GET" requests, and receiving the "DATA" responses, synchronously. Every transaction is completed before the next one starts, and the socket connection is kept up the entire time.

The problem is, that after some seemingly random number of transfers (as few as 4, as many as 300), a transfer will unexpectedly stall. It stalls for the full 30 seconds, and then a socket timeout error is raised on the client.

At this point, I have inspected the client's socket and I can see (via manually calling `sock.recv(4096, socket.MSG_PEEK)` that there is no data pending on this side. It is genuinely out of data, and waiting for more. On the server side, it is still in the middle of the `async_write()` operation, with data still to send. There's no error on the server side (the timeout on the server is currently infinite).

I've looked with Wireshark and I can see that the last few packets on the stream are OK - there are no retransmissions or errors. The network is reliable and fast, over a small 1Gb Ethernet switch. Wireshark just shows that everything has stopped, dead.

If I invoke `pdb` when the socket timeout exception occurs, then set the socket to non-blocking and do a peek, I receive:

```
*** BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

With or without the blocking socket, if I send a small amount of data from the client to the server with `sock.send(b"ping")`, the following happens immediately:

1. the server completes the send and invokes the `async_write()`'s completion handler, with the bytes_transferred equal to what I'd expect to see. From the server's point of view, the transfer is complete.
2. the client now has data available on the socket to receive, and it can do so if I manually call `sock.recv(4096)`.

So the stall is cleared by sending data in the *opposite* direction.

I don't understand why this might stall on occasion, and why would a transfer in one direction require data to be send in the opposite direction to exit the stall? Is there a subtle feature of sending large amounts of data over TCP that I need to be aware of?

Comment: Would be useful to include the server code, seeing that it takes the client to unblock the server, the failure may in fact be on the server side.  Would be good to create a minimum reproducible example on the server side, during that process if you can't reproduce the issue it may point you towards the difference that is required to correct the problem on the server side.

Comment: There's nothing in the TCP protocol itself that requires a client to send data to unblock transmission.  I too suspect some kind of bug in the server codebase.

Comment: Thanks @metatoaster and Jeremy Friesner, you both make a good point and I will look to create a minimum example of the server, as time permits.

Comment: Update - I found an issue with ARM64 memcpy from mmapped Device (physical) memory to unaligned destination addresses, which was being invoked by `async_write()`'s support for a sequence of buffers and possibly causing undefined behaviour on the socket. By ensuring that the size of the first chunk (the header) is a multiple of 8 bytes, I was able to restore proper behaviour, and this issue is no longer occurring. I can't explain exactly why opposite data was required. I've added a summary to the end of my question.

Comment: I will consider closing this question if anyone recommends that I should. However it could be useful information for anyone using ARM64 with `async_write` that the data writes in a sequence of buffers must be aligned if copying from Device memory... pretty niche though.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the solution. There's some background I didn't mention originally as I thought at the time that it would cloud the issue, but it was actually the cause, as I discovered while putting together the minimum example.

There's a documented issue with `memcpy` alignment on mmapped "Device" memory on some ARM64 platforms:

https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ka004708/latest

Essentially the issue is that my `boost::asio` code was doing the following, to write data to the socket from a memory-mapped device (I use a mmapped UDmaBuf device but it could have been UIO also, I suspect):

```
        // not copied verbatim - does not work standalone

        std::uint8_t * data = get_memory_map();  // returns pointer from open()/mmap() etc.

        this->header = "DATA";
        this->footer = "END";

        boost::asio::async_write(
                socket_,
                std::array { io::buffer(this->header),
                             io::buffer(data, length),
                             io::buffer(this->footer) },,
                [me = shared_from_this()](const error_code & ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred){
                    if (ec) {
                        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << ec;
                    }
                }
        );
```

The issue here is that the `async_write()` call, taking the `std::array` of three items, builds a "packet". The first part is taken from the `header` buffer, which in this case is 4 bytes. Then the main data is copied from the mmapped `data` pointer, and this is where the problem occurs, because the destination pointer (starting at the 5th byte into the "packet") is not aligned to a 64-bit boundary. Most of the time, unfortunately, this works, but there are certain lengths of data that seem to trigger weird socket issues. In some cases an obvious "Bad Address" error occurs from the system call, and in others a different amount of data is copied than is requested (which is super-weird), and I think this is what was causing my client/server protocol to get out of sync. This doesn't entirely explain why the socket needed data in the opposite direction to "unstick" it, but it may be due to undefined behaviour on the server side.

By padding the "DATA" header to a multiple of 8 bytes, I've been able to solve the issue and get 100% reliable transmission in this situation.

I also found an alternative solution that works for `boost::asio::async_write()` but *does not work* for `boost::asio::write()` (synchronous write). By splitting the sequence into three distinct and separate `async_write()` calls (one for the header, one for the data from the mmap, and one for the footer) nested in each other's completion handlers to serialise them properly, I do not need to pad the header. But if I try three distinct and separate `write()` calls, the original problem manifests. I suspect this may be to differences in the way `boost::asio` composes a buffer once written to the socket - perhaps `async_write()` always uses a new buffer for each write (hence always aligned), but `write()` just appends to an existing buffer?